# How to Update Visual Studio Code Portable?

Tags: visual-studio-code, updates, portable-applications

I typically update the standard version of `Visual Studio Code` by clicking `Help => Check for Updates` (or just letting it update automatically in the background), but this option is missing from the `Help` menu in the portable version. Furthermore, it doesn't update automatically in the background despite the fact that I haven't overridden the following default settings:

`"update.channel": "default",`
`"update.enableWindowsBackgroundUpdates": true,`

Are there any other ways to update the portable version of Visual Studio Code, or do I have to manually uninstall/reinstall it every time a major update is released?

Comment: I don't use the portable version, but I suspect that the "automatic update" feature is a part of the installer.

Comment: So do you think that running the portable installer will result in the program being detected and updated (rather than installed)?

Comment: I re-ran the installer in the parent directory of the `VS Code Portable` folder, and it did indeed update the program. However, it only achieved this because it re-installed `Visual Studio Code Portable` from scratch, which took as much time as a portable installation and also resulted in my debugger configurations being reset (i.e. the `launch.json` file was cleared).I was able to recover the configurations from a backup file, but as a result of all this I wouldn't say that re-installation is a very convenient way to update a portable installation.

Comment: Official doc: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/portable#_update-portable-vs-code

Answer (score 9):

> After unzipping the VS Code download, simply create a data folder within Code's folder:

```
|- VSCode-win32-x64-1.25.0-insider
|   |- Code.exe (or code executable)
|   |- data
|   |- ...
```

> The data folder can be moved to other VS Code installations. This is useful for updating your portable Code version: simply move the data folder to a newer extracted version of VS Code.
>
> On Windows and Linux, you can update VS Code by copying the data folder over to a more recent version of VS Code.

[From their docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/portable#_update-portable-vs-code)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the one that is downloaded from github, you can just set up a github repository in your pc, pull from the github repo, and check for updates from time to time.

Comment: Is there a way to do that which doesn't involve setting up the repository on the PC? I use the portable version on a USB key, which I run from multiple computers, so I can't depend on host directories/files for my processes.

Comment: There is also a portable version of Github here:
https://github.com/daemondevin/GitHubDesktopPortable